# How do I properly structure the following models in a way that will allow a successful code first migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, ef-code-first, cascading-deletes

Thanks for looking.

I want to create the following `Image` domain model:

```
    [Table("Image")]    
    public class Image
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a title.")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a caption.")]
        public string Caption { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a file.")]
        public string File { get; set; }
    }
```

Then, I want multiple other models to make use of it.  For example:

```
[Table("Product")]
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a title.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a description.")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }       
}

[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }        
}
```

When managing (creating) a `Product` or `User` I **do** want for a SINGLE image to be required.  Also, the image used for `Product` or `User` will not be used by any other entity.

## The Problem

When I attempt to deploy this code first model to the database via Package Manager Console (`PM> update-database`), I get the following error:

`Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Product_dbo.Image_ImageId' on table 'Product' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.`

So the message returned is suggesting that I alter the SQL statements which won't work since I am automating this via Package Manager Console / CodeFirst.

## The Question

That said, how do I create a common `Image` Entity Model, use it as a required property in multiple other entities, and still deploy via CodeFirst without violating `multiple cascade paths` rules?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your scenario, step by step, and I didn't get any errors. However, I believe that you already have an existing database, which might cause the error you described above.

To solve the `cycles or multiple cascade paths error`, just map the relationships using Fluent API, like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
        .HasRequired(i => i.Image)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(i => i.ImageId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasRequired(i => i.Image)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(i => i.ImageId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

I believe it should be enough to solve your problem.

Your second problem is more complicated:

> When managing (creating) a Product or User I do want for a SINGLE
>   image to be required. Also, the image used for Product or User will
>   not be used by any other entity.

With your current database structure, I can't see how it can be possible at database level. The easiest workarounds I can imagine are:

1. Create a separated `Image` entity (like UserImage, ProductImage) for `Users` and `Projects` (which doesn't worth in my opinion)
2. Validate the relationship at application level

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help Fabio!